# Oracle MAF : Clear form in create new screen at first time

Tags: java, oracle-maf

I have created two types of POC, one is with UI generator and another without.

When I'm using UI generator by calling `#{bindings.CreateEmployee.execute}` it is showing plain form, when I use the same without UI generator it is always showing filled form with first data from DB.

This happens only at first time, if I come back to the same screen again everything is fine. How I can fix this issue. Anybody having idea?

---

**Edit:**
I'm using taskflow, From `EmployeeList.amx` the flow will goto `Employee.amx`(Here I will be having the Employee form)

**EmployeeList.amx:**

```
<amx:commandLink actionListener="#{bindings.CreateEmployee.execute}"  action="goToEmployee"
                         id="cb4" text="Create Employee">
```

**EmplopyeePageDef.xml:**

```
<executables>
    <variableIterator id="variables">
      <variable Name="find_searchValue" Type="java.lang.String"/>
    </variableIterator>
    <iterator id="EmployeeServiceDCIterator" Binds="root" DataControl="EmployeeServiceDC"
              RangeSize="25"/>
    <accessorIterator id="EmployeeIterator" MasterBinding="EmployeeServiceDCIterator"
                      Binds="Employee" BeanClass="package.Employee"
                      DataControl="EmployeeServiceDC" RangeSize="25"/>
</executables>

<bindings>
     <action id="CreateEmployee" RequiresUpdateModel="true" Action="createRow"
            IterBinding="EmployeeIterator"/>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Sound like you have an issue with your current row. Are you using a taskflow where you call the create method and then go to your page or ... ?

Comment: Yeah i'm using it, Please check the above update in question.

Comment: Are you sure that the current row of your Employee iterator is pointing to your newly created Employee?

Comment: you are talking about page definition xml file right? if so I have already pasted along with question. Please be bit clear if something else.